# Learning to optimize the script

Tags: jquery

Hi all this I'm learning how to write some jquery ...i wish can some how actually teach n guide how i can actually optimize the script i wrote below it's quite messy ...

```
jQuery('#readywear2').hover(function() 
{ $("<div class=\"popbg\"></div>").insertBefore(".fluid_container");
    jQuery('.popbg').css("background-image", "url(images/hover/hove-ready.jpg)"); 
}); 


    jQuery('#readywear2').mouseout(function() 
{ 
    jQuery('.popbg').remove(); 
}); 


jQuery('#corpdesign2').hover(function() 
{ $("<div class=\"popbg\"></div>").insertBefore(".fluid_container");
    jQuery('.popbg').css("background-image", "url(images/hover/hover-design.jpg)"); 
}); 

    jQuery('#corpdesign2').mouseout(function() 
{
    jQuery('.popbg').remove(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the exercise funny and original. Here's my go :

```
var $fluidContainer = $(".fluid_container"); // cache often accessed objects for performance

$('#readywear2')
    .hover(function(){
        $("<div class='popbg'></div>").insertBefore($fluidContainer);
        $('.popbg').css("background-image", "url(images/hover/hove-ready.jpg)"); 
    }, function(){ // done on mouse out
        $('.popbg').remove();
});

$('#corpdesign2')
    .hover(function(){
        $("<div class='popbg'></div>").insertBefore($fluidContainer);
        $('.popbg').css("background-image", "url(images/hover/hover-design.jpg)"); 
    }, function(){
        $('.popbg').remove(); 
});
```